# Canon printer LBP2900B in Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon 32bit

Tags: printer, canon

I have been trying to install **Canon laser printer LBP2900B** in Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon 32bit.

Whenever I give a print order monitor will say " printing" ! After 2 seconds it will say," printing cancelled " !

When i check the printer status( captstatusui -P LBP2900),the message i am getting is:

```
Communication error:
    - is the printer turned on ?
    - is the cable correctly connected ?
```

I reconnected the cable,still the same error message !I am not getting " **Ready to print** " message after running the command **captstatusui -P LBP2900**

[[image: Click to see screen shot]

And in the terminal it says:  "**(captstatusui:8733): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 10 was not found when attempting to remove it** "

I tried many versions of CAPT driver from canon site including **latest 2.7** !
The main link i referred is:

http://www.e-lokam.com/internetsoftware/cannon-lbp-2900b-printer-installation-in-mint-16/

Another link itried :

https://radu.cotescu.com/how-to-install-canon-lbp-printers-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

First you turn on the cpu or laptop  and give time to 10 or 15 min to turn the printer after go to terminal and check the printer status in terminal by using this command:  `captstatusui -P LBP2900`, it shows what is printer's current status, printer is not yet ready or some error is coming mean restart the CPU or laptop and check the status, still printer get ready to print.

Use this file to install the via synaptic driver
portserve, gsfonts, gsfonts-other, gsfonts-x11

Answer (score 0):

I had a the same printer and there isn't driver for this model, I lost months in search of it.
And even if there were there would be other problems, I am sorry